# Ubuntu preset the letter ‘e’ to all entries I make

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bug-reporting, debug

I am a new Ubuntu user. I have an odd problem, namely that the letter ‘e’ is added to the beginning of all entries I make. I recently added a keyboard short cut (ctrl + f) but following the problem above I also deleted it. Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. So whenever I type something into the command prompt or the search tab, an ‘e’ is added to the beginning of the entry along with some temporary underlining beneath the entry. Any idea what the reason for this is and how I can solve it? Thanks for your help! I am using 20.04 by the way.

Comment: same thing here, no idea whats is going on.